# Facebook likes reset after moving to HTTPS

Tags: https, facebook, like

I've got a question regarding the Facebook *like* button. 
We worked on a piece recently that embeds a number of social share buttons (please see the source code below).

When the piece was released, it was on HTTP, and received over 2k *likes* (the URL 'slug' hasn't changed at all). The site was recently migrated to permanent-on HTTPS, and the *like* data has been reset, and we've been left with 50 new, recent *likes*.

If you see in the source code, the URL is set explicitly to like the HTTP version, which I believe to be correct. Can anyone help me work out what's happened here?

Here's the HTML bit of the *like* button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.harveywatersofteners.co.uk/history-interior-design" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543089/having-facebook-likes-accumulate-over-https-and-http

Answer (score 1):

Frank comment tells you what you should do, but if you don't want to do it, you can simply increase the number of Facebook "likes" with a very easy trick a found recently, first of all you must know that Facebook "likes" are likes and comments, so if you want to increase this number you can go to you Facebook and you will share this URL (change the privacy in order that nobody can see this status) then you will write comments in your own status, let's say 5 comments, finally you can go to the page and reload, you will see that you have 6 more Facebook "likes"...

It is not a way to solve your problem, but you can use it to reach your goal...

Answer (score 0):

for G+ it's easy as you have to modify just the Google+ sharing buttons so that you will share the URL on http and not on https.

when it comes to fb you need to:

1. use the debug interface to check out your urls
2. click on "scrape again" - all your social counts will get to zero
3. update rel = canonical and make the http version the preferred one but just for FB crawlers
4. identify FB crawler ; here depends on what you are using;